# Show 1 Safari window on all desktops and not whole Safari app

Tags: macos

I want to have one Safari window show on all my desktops, I can't figure out how. Right clicking the app icon > options > assign to all desktops, but this will show every single Safari window on all my desktops.

How can I show only 1 window on all of my desktops?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Spaces just doesn't work that way, I'm afraid. Any Space/Desktop assignment is for the entire app, not any single window.

A workaround would be to run that single window in a different browser.

Comment: On Windows 10/11 it's possible. There has to be demand for this therefore an app must exist to make this possible on MacOS? Are you aware of any? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows can do it presumably because each window is a separate independent process. Mac doesn't work that way.

Comment: Makes sense. So you would say on a software level you wouldn't be able to turn this specific functionality into a possibility?

Comment: Not without rewriting Spaces ;) Basically, development on Spaces stopped when fullscreen was added, & as Apple transitioned to laptops rather than desktops. The only improvements in the last decade have been to fullscreen functionality.